# Sharepoint 2010: is it possible to extend an Fab40 site template?

Tags: templates, sharepoint-2010

I just tried using one of the fab40 templates... however, it doesn't do everything I would want so I would like to extend it.  My guess is that since it is packaged up as an wsp, that this isn't possible without the source.  I find it hard to believe that source would not be provided, am I not looking in the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/71664b6d-6c17-46e0-8bdf-becca0337cc6/

Once you have the files, you can put them into your own Visual Studio SharePoint project. It would be best to change any GUIDs, layouts file names, and site definition codes and paths to avoid collisions with the original Fab 40 template. You can add a reference to any custom Fab 40 DLL in your project, but the wsp will not contain the C# code. However, you should be able to get the code from [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) if you need it.